# How to convert JSON to html select value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hello anyone please help me, i need to use JSON data in url contain JSON data somexample.json to html select droplist with javascript.
I have tried to find solution but have not get solution, please anyone help me on this.

{
    "details":{
    "numberOfBundles":14,
      "bundles":[
         {
            "amount":100.0,
            "description":"200min Onnet Voice",
            "typeCode":153
         },
         {
            "amount":1200.0,
            "description":"1GB Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":101
         },
         {
            "amount":400.0,
            "description":"5GB Night & Weekend Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":162
         },
         {
            "amount":3000.0,
            "description":"3GB Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":102
         },
         {
            "amount":5000.0,
            "description":"5GB Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":161
         },
         {
            "amount":5000.0,
            "description":"7GB Anytime data plan",
            "typeCode":164
         },
         {
            "amount":7500.0,
            "description":"10GB Night & Weekend Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":144
         },
         {
            "amount":9000.0,
            "description":"10GB Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":103
         },
         {
            "amount":14000.0,
            "description":"20GB Night & Weekend Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":145
         },
         {
            "amount":17000.0,
            "description":"20GB Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":104
         },
         {
            "amount":36000.0,
            "description":"50GB Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":105
         },
         {
            "amount":70000.0,
            "description":"100GB Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":142
         },
         {
            "amount":5E+5,
            "description":"500MB Data Bundle",
            "typeCode":100
    },
    {
    "amount":5E+5,
    "description":"200GB Data Bundle",
    "typeCode":143
    }
    ]
    }
    }

I need html select like.

```
<select name="internetbundle">
<option value="500.00">5GB Night & Weekend Data Bundle</option>
<option value="3000.00">3GB Data Bundle</option>
<option value="5000.00">7GB Anytime data plan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to iterate over the bundle and append through jQuery.

```
json.details.bundle.forEach(function(value) {   
var value = value.amount
var data = value.description
var id = value.typeCode
$('select[name="internetbundle"]').append('<option id="'+id+'" 
    value="'+value+'">'+data+'</option>');
)}
```

Comment: The OP has not specified jQuery.

Comment: Sorry how can i do on pure javascript without using jQuery.